# Pylons middleware 404

Tags: python, pylons

i'm new to Python and Pylons and want to know how it is possible to cancle the start routin of the pylons app.

I found the middleware and want to do something like this:

```
    if error:
        abort(404)
```

But this brings me a 500 internal Server Error Message if error is true instead of a 404 Not Found Message.

Could anyone tell me how i can interupt start routin of pylons?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a message in the call:

```
abort(404,"404 Not Found");
```

As well, you can customize the error documents. See:
http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/pylonsdocs/Error+Documents#changing-the-template

Comment: this brings me the same result as if i just do a abort(404) and i also don't want to custimze error messages. I want to stop/leave the make_app def in the middleware.py so the pylons app doesn't show up in the browser because error is true in my case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the condition not abort.

Try this way:

```
def test(self):
  username = ''
  if not username:
    abort(404)
```